# Bug in receiving data using MPC framework in libgdx game

Tags: ios, libgdx, multipeer-connectivity, robovm

We're trying to make a multipeer connection between two devices using MPC framework in libgdx game.

What generally we've done successfully:

1. Devices are connecting, session is establishing correctly.
2. After session is established nearBrowser and nearAdvertiser stop
   doing their stuff.
3. Then we do transition to the game scene. In the new scene one device
   can send a message to another.
4. DidReceiveData method from Session Delegate is called and there
   we've got right messages for both devices.
5. After this we send to libgdx message for updating content (in main
   gdx thread).

BUT after a while when some device received data it immediately crashes. Sometimes it happens on 10th receiving, sometimes after 200th. Crash appears only on the device that received message. It doesn't matter how long  they are connected. Crash appears after all methods have done their work with data. So we don't know where exactly error happens.

```
// MCSession delegate method

public void didReceiveData(MCSession session, NSData data, MCPeerID peerID) {

 //there we make userInfoData

 // 
 DispatchQueue.getMainQueue().async(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
        NSNotificationCenter.getDefaultCenter().postNotification(new NSString("didReceiveData"), null,  userInfoData);
  }
  });

}

// Register observer in NSNotificationCenter
// NSNotificationCenter.getDefaultCenter().addObserver(this, Selector.register("updateDataWithNotification:"), new NSString("didReceiveData"), null);

// This method is called when device has received new data

@Method
private void updateDataWithNotification(NSNotification notification){

 userInfoDict = notification.getUserInfo();
 data = (NSData) userInfoDict.get(new NSString("data"));
 strBytes =  new String(data.getBytes());

 // i'm not sure this Gdx.app.postRunnable is really needed         
 Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
  SBGlobalMessanger.getInstance().readBluetoothMessage(BluetoothData.RC_MESSAGE, strBytes);
    }
 });
}
```

The questions are:
Where is the bug? And how can we fix it?

Comment: I don't see a bug.  But your code is overly complicated.  Why do you need a signal?  You are doing the correct thing by dispatching to the main queue from the delegate method (which runs in another queue) but why not just call a handler method directly, without a signal?

Comment: Anyway even if i handle data directly i get the crash. The reason  for using notifications is decoupling classes. One singleton handler implements MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate. Second class implements another interfaces that are on the higher level of abstraction. That's why i created 2 classes which are using observer instead of 1 big.

Comment: You can decouple without using notification.  I used another class Messenger  so my didReceiveData does : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { messenger.receive(data!)  }.  I could be wrong, just suggesting that the bug is some complex interaction between notifications and queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in robovm plugin. In debug mode it made build that crushed. After making release build bug disappeared. The thing i have learned after working with robovm + libgdx is if you have strange bug just make a release build. It seems that this kind of bugs was eliminated with the last release of robovm 1.3 (i haven't try it out yet).